# Getting Access Token

Tags: php, facebook, api, access-token

I have tried accessing the access token using the code below:

```
$code=$_REQUEST['code'];

if(empty($code)) {
    $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) 
    . "&scope=publish_stream,user_photo_video_tags";
    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
  }

  $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) 
    . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret 
    . "&code=" . $code;
    $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
    $params = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);
    $access_token = $params['access_token'];
```

It works fine but when the user tries to use the application for the second time, there is no smooth flow while trying to authorize the user.

So, my question is how do I make sure that there smooth flow while trying to authorize the users?

Answer (score 0):

To do user authorization smoothly I recommend you to use the latest [Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk)

Here's an example script of mine which handles the user authorization:

```
// init new facebook class instance with app info
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => 'YOUR APP ID',
'secret' => 'YOUR APP SECRET'
));

// get user UID
$fb_user_id = $facebook->getUser();

// get the url where to redirect the user
$location = "". $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'publish_stream'));

// check if we have valid user
if ($fb_user_id) {
try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $fb_user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');   

} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $fb_user_id = NULL;
    // seems we don't have enough permissions
    // we use javascript to redirect user instead of header() due to Facebook bug
    print '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> top.location.href="'. $location .'"; </script>';

    // kill the code so nothing else will happen before user gives us permissions
    die();
}

} else {
// seems our user hasn't logged in, redirect him to a FB login page

print '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> top.location.href="'. $location .'"; </script>';

// kill the code so nothing else will happen before user gives us permissions
die();
}

// at this point we have an logged in user who has given permissions to our APP
// basic user info can be fetched easily
print "User access token is: ". $facebook->getAccessToken();
```